# What happened to the Marvel timeline where Thor stole Mjolnir from himself?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Thor goes back in time to extract the Reality Stone from Jame Foster, but when he does so, he also summons Mjolnir and takes it with him. Does that mean that the Thor in that timeline doesn't have his hammer?

Comment: Did you not notice that Captain America put Mjolnir back at the same moment it left?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Steve takes Mjolnir back with him to 2013 when he returns the Reality Stone back to the moment it was taken in that timeline so it never actually leaves 2013. You can see he carries it to the platform with him and it is seen at his feet before he jumps back.

[image: Steve holds the suitcase on the platform ready to jump back with Mjolnir at his feet]

Comment: Was he actually holding it when he jumped? I don't recall either way.  If he wasn't then it should have stayed on the platform when he went through.

Comment: @JK. yeah he picks it up just before the jump.

Comment: Why does this the Cap in this capture look like an action figure?

Answer (score 12):

When Steve goes back through time to return the various stones (including the one that's going back to Asgard) he takes Mjolnir with him. It seems highly likely that the goal was to return it to its appropriate place in time.

[image]

Per the [film script](https://disneystudiosawards.s3.amazonaws.com/avengers-endgame/Avengers_Endgame.pdf).

> **BUCKY BARNES** (CONT'D): Gonna miss you, buddy.
>
> **STEVE:** It’s going to be okay, Buck.
>
> [Steve picks up Mjolnir and takes his place on the platform.]
>
> [SAM LOOKS TO SMART HULK AT THE CONSOLE.]